# How to specify in azure devops 2019 a different sprint capacity according to the day?

Tags: azure-devops-server-2019

I'm using Azure DevOps Server 2019 udpate 1.1.
Referring to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/sprints/set-capacity?view=azure-devops, I didn't find any way to track by web interface a different sprint capacity according to the day. Normally my capacity for a team T is 8 hours per day. I think that is normal that in some day my capacity for a team T can be for example 6 hours per day, and another day my capacity for the same team T can be 4 hours per day. How can set these different capacity according to the day? Maybe there is some way provided by time tracker extension of I can use REST-API?

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: Sorry for delay. I found this other old stackoverflow question very similar to my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734051/how-to-plan-user-capacity-per-day-on-tfs12-scrum-template-2-0. Furthermore I found a question about this topic on time tracker extension here https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=7pace.Timetracker&ssr=false#qna. Ultimately, as you already confirmed I did not find any native functionality offered by Azure DevOps or marketplace extension useful for this scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can set these different capacity according to the day?

I am afraid that there is no out-of-the-box feature in azure devops to achieve this requirement. Setting different capacity per day is currently not supported in azure devops.

You can refer to this [case](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/217388/set-different-capacity-per-day-per-member.html) with similar issue.

As workaround , you can update a team member's capacity by calling [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/capacities/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) according to actual needs.

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations/{iterationId}/capacities/{teamMemberId}?api-version=5.0
```

Apart from the negative answer, I think what you want is a good idea! So I post a feature request [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1121203/set-different-capacity-per-day-1.html) in DC forum. You could vote that suggestion ticket and share your comment there,the product team would provide the updates if they view it. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

Comment: If we consider a typical sprint capacity of 8 hours per day, could be a feasible workaround to manually change sprint capacity (using REST-API or web interface shown at point 4 of this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/sprints/set-capacity?view=azure-devops-2019#set-capacity-for-the-team-and-team-members) only when it is necessary? More in details: 
- the change must be done in the exact day in which it is necessary, for instance set 6 hours
- in next day, if the change is not more necessary, the sprint capacity can be reset to 8 hours

Comment: What would be the body of this PATCH call? I am trying to edit "Days off" per developer